# geoJson parse issue

Tags: ajax, parsing, geojson

I keep getting an error on my code that says:
"AJAX Error: parsererror SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data"

Or it will sometimes say:
"GeoJSON file not found"

Ive done all thats been suggested but just seem to be going round in circles - Seems to be with my file name i think but its in the same directory as my php file?

```
    <?php
header("Content-Type: application/json");

// Enable error reporting for debugging purposes
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('user_agent', 'Your-Application-Name');

// Check if 'country' parameter is provided
if (!isset($_REQUEST['country'])) {
    // Return an error response if the 'country' parameter is missing
    echo json_encode(array(
        'status' => array(
            'code' => 400,
            'name' => 'Bad Request',
            'description' => 'Country parameter is missing'
        ),
        'data' => null
    ));
    exit();
}

// Get the user-specified country from the request
$userCountry = $_REQUEST['country'];

// Use a geocoding service to obtain coordinates
$geocodingUrl = 'https://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/search?format=json&q=' . urlencode($userCountry);
$geocodingData = file_get_contents($geocodingUrl);
$geocodingResult = json_decode($geocodingData, true);

if (empty($geocodingResult)) {
    // Return an error response if the geocoding service does not provide coordinates
    echo json_encode(array(
        'status' => array(
            'code' => 404,
            'name' => 'Not Found',
            'description' => 'Coordinates not found for the specified country'
        ),
        'data' => null
    ));
    exit();
}

// Debugging information
echo "Current working directory: " . getcwd() . "<br>";

// File existence check for GeoJSON file
$geoJsonFilePath = "libs/countryBorders.geo.json";
echo "File exists: " . (file_exists($geoJsonFilePath) ? 'Yes' : 'No') . "<br>";

if (!file_exists($geoJsonFilePath)) {
    // Return an error response if the GeoJSON file is not found
    echo json_encode(array(
        'status' => array(
            'code' => 404,
            'name' => 'Not Found',
            'description' => 'GeoJSON file not found'
        ),
        'data' => null
    ));
    exit();
}

// Read the GeoJSON file
$geoJsonData = file_get_contents($geoJsonFilePath);
$geoJsonArray = json_decode($geoJsonData, true);

// Extract coordinates from the geocoding result
$latitude = $geocodingResult[0]['lat'];
$longitude = $geocodingResult[0]['lon'];


// Read the GeoJSON file
$geoJsonData = file_get_contents("libs/countryBorders.geo.json");
$geoJsonArray = json_decode($geoJsonData, true);


// Extract country codes and names
$countries = array();
foreach ($geoJsonArray['features'] as $feature) {
    $properties = $feature['properties'];
    $country = array(
        'code' => $properties['ISO_A2'],
        'name' => $properties['ADMIN'],
        'latitude' => $latitude,
        'longitude' => $longitude
    );
    $countries[] = $country;
}

$targetCountryCode = '';  
$targetCountry = null; 

foreach ($countries as $country) {
    if ($country['code'] === $targetCountryCode) {
        $targetCountry = $country;
        break;
    }
}

if ($targetCountry !== null) {
    // Return the border information for the specific country code
    echo json_encode(array(
        'status' => array(
            'code' => 200,
            'name' => 'OK',
            'description' => 'Request successful'
        ),
        'data' => $targetCountry,
        'latitude' => $latitude,
        'longitude' => $longitude
    ));
} else {
    // Return an error response if the country code is not found
    echo json_encode(array(
        'status' => array(
            'code' => 404,
            'name' => 'Not Found',
            'description' => 'Country code not found'
        ),
        'data' => null
    ));
}
```

my geoJson file is called countryBorders.geo.json

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {

    /* SECTION FOR LEAFLET MAP BASIC SETTINGS */

    // Creates a Leaflet Map and sets the initial view/starting point with coordinates
    const map = L.map('map').setView([0, 0], 2);

    // Adds the OpenStreetMap layer to the map and sets the max zoom level 
    const OpenStreetMap_Mapnik = L.tileLayer('https://tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
        maxZoom: 19,
        attribution: '&copy; <a href="http://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a>'
    }).addTo(map);

    // Feature Group 
    let featureGroup = L.featureGroup().addTo(map);

    // Load your GeoJSON data and add it to the FeatureGroup
    $.getJSON('libs/countryBorders.geo.json', function (data) {

        let geoJsonLayer = L.geoJSON(data, {
            style: {
                color: 'black',
                weight: 0.5,
                fillOpacity: 0
            }
        });

        // Add the GeoJSON layer to the FeatureGroup
        geoJsonLayer.addTo(featureGroup);

        // Fit the map view to the bounds of the FeatureGroup
        map.fitBounds(featureGroup.getBounds());

    });

    console.log('FeatureGroup:', featureGroup);

    // Create a GeoJSON layer
    let countryBordersLayer = L.geoJSON().addTo(map);


    // Load countryBorders.geo.json data and add it to the GeoJSON layer
    $.getJSON('libs/countryBorders.geo.json', function (data) {
        // Assuming 'countryBordersLayer' is a GeoJSON layer, add the data to it
        countryBordersLayer.addData(data);
    });

    // Will zoom into the user's location once shared - geolocation
    map.locate({ setView: true, maxZoom: 16 });

    // Places a marker in the user's location to show accuracy
    function onLocationFound(e) {
        const radius = e.accuracy;

        L.marker(e.latlng).addTo(map)
            .bindPopup("You are within " + radius + " meters from this point").openPopup();

        L.circle(e.latlng, radius).addTo(map);
    }

    // Defines functions of whether the location of the user was found or error if not
    map.on('locationfound', onLocationFound);

    // Error message if the geolocation failed    
    function onLocationError(e) {
        alert(e.message);
    }

    map.on('locationerror', onLocationError);

    /* SECTION FOR USER INPUT AND LEAFLET MAP MOVING TO THAT COUNTRY */

    document.getElementById('btnRun').addEventListener('click', function () {

        // Retrieves user input 
        let country = document.getElementById('country').value;

        console.log('country:', country);

        // Use OpenStreetMap Nominatim for geocoding
        let geocodeUrl = 'https://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/search?format=json&q=' + encodeURIComponent(country);

        function successCallback(position) {
            // Handle success, e.g., update the map or perform other actions
        }
        
        function errorCallback(error) {
            // Handle error, e.g., display an error message
            console.error('Error getting geolocation:', error.message);
        }

        // Make an AJAX request to get the geocoded data
        fetch(geocodeUrl)
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(data => {
                // Get the first result (assuming it's the most relevant)
                let result = data[0];

                // Check if a valid result is obtained
                if (result) {
                    var lat = parseFloat(result.lat);
                    var lon = parseFloat(result.lon);

                    // Set the map view to the user's country
                    map.setView([lat, lon], 6);
                    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(successCallback, errorCallback);
                } else {
                    console.error('Unable to geocode user input.');
                }
            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.error('Error fetching geocoding data:', error);
            });

        // API Call 
        // Make an AJAX request to the PHP script
        $.ajax({
            url: "libs/countryBorders.php",
            type: 'GET',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: {
                country: $('#country').val(),
            },

            // Callback function to handle a successful result
            success: function (result) {

                console.log(result);

                if (result && result.status && result.status.name === "ok") {

                    let countryInfo = result.data.geonames[0];
                    let latitude = result.data[0].latitude;
                    let longitude = result.data[0].longitude;

                    $('.info-box').html('<p>Country: ' + countryInfo.name + '</p>' +
                        '<p>Code: ' + countryInfo.code + '</p>' +
                        '<p>Latitude: ' + latitude + '</p>' +
                        '<p>Longitude: ' + longitude + '</p>');

                    // Update the Leaflet map to zoom into the specified country based on the obtained coordinates
                    map.setView([latitude, longitude], 10);

                    // Add a marker at the specified coordinates
                    L.marker([latitude, longitude]).addTo(map)
                        .bindPopup('Country: ' + countryInfo.name)
                        .openPopup();

                    $('#txtCapital').html(result.data.capital);
                    $('#txtPopulation').html(result.data.population);
                    $('#txtCurrency').html(result.data.currency);
                    $('#txtLanguage').html(result.data.language);

                    let coordinates = 'Latitude: ' + countryInfo.north + ', Longitude: ' + countryInfo.east;
                    $('#txtCoordinates').html(coordinates);

                    $('#countryInfoResults').show();
                } else {
                    // Handle other cases, e.g., display an error message
                    console.error("Error:", result ? result.status.description : "Unknown error");
                }

                // Assuming 'data' is the API response
                let apiInformation = JSON.stringify(result, null, 2); // Convert data to a formatted JSON string

                // Display the API information in the element with ID 'countryInfoResults'
                $('#countryInfoResults').text(apiInformation);
            },

            // Callback function to handle the error in the AJAX request
            error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                console.error("AJAX Error:", textStatus, errorThrown);
                console.log('Response Text:', jqXHR.responseText);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: If the first character in your JSON data is an unexpected character, that means that your data isn't actually a JSON document. In my experience, if you're fetching data from a web API and expect the response to be a JSON document, then this sort of error often means that the API (or the web server where it is hosted) has returned some kind of HTML error page instead. Having said that though, what are you expecting the response from `libs/countryBorders.php` in the last `$.ajax` in your JavaScript code to be? If that's a file of PHP code rather than a JSON file then that's probably the problem.

Comment: PS you may want to add the [php] and [javascript] tags to your question, which will increase the chances of it being seen by people who know those languages and can answer your question.